# How to create a MySQL with Primary Key not an auto increment

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

Am trying to create the following table:

```
create table Cust (Name varchar(50) UNIQUE, Cat1 varchar(50), RowID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY (Name));
```

the error I get is

> Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it
>   must be defined as a key

I want to index by the "Name", not the RowID.  So even if I end it with:

```
...PRIMARY KEY (Name, RowID));
```

It fails.  Of course `...PRIMARY KEY (RowID, Name));` works but is not what I want.

Can someone help me see the light please?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You just need to make a KEY (aka index) for the auto-inc column. It doesn't have to be the primary key, but it must be the left-most column in some index.

```
create table Cust (
  Name varchar(50), 
  Cat1 varchar(50), 
  RowID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  PRIMARY KEY (Name),
  KEY (RowId)
);
```

Don't add the UNIQUE option to the name column. That creates an extra superfluous unique index, which you don't need. Any PRIMARY KEY is already unique.

I'll comment that auto-inc is not the same thing as rowid. Don't expect auto-inc to have consecutive values.

Comment: As someone who works in different DBs, I'm trying to understand this answer. I just want to make sure that the OP's error was essentially complaining that an AUTO_INCREMENT column needs to be indexed, and has nothing to do with trying to create a PRIMARY KEY that does not include the AUTO_INCREMENT, right?

Comment: Yes, that's how I interpreted the question. It's a bit unclear. The error happened because they tried to make a column auto-inc even though it's not an indexed column.